# Bible with commentaries of the Church Fathers

Tags: church-fathers, resource-request, bible-commentary

I am looking for a Bible gathering commentaries of the Church Fathers verse by verse.
Is there such a book or website?

Comment: This is available online, but requires a login. I assume logins can be attributed to students or other deserving persons. [Duke University](https://guides.library.duke.edu/c.php?g=289359&p=7815954). A second hand copy of the Romans volume (Edward Bray) is available for £20.99.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [Ancient Christian Commentary on Scripture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Christian_Commentary_on_Scripture) is the leading commentary series collecting the church fathers. At 29 volumes would be a big investment to buy, but most theological colleges/seminaries probably have a copy. It's also available in [Accordance for $329USD](https://accordancebible.com/product/ancient-christian-commentary-on-scripture-complete-29-volume-set/) and [Logos for $500USD](https://www.logos.com/product/31152/ancient-christian-commentary-on-scripture-complete-set-updated-edition-accs).

Answer (score 12):

The [Catena Bible](https://catenabible.com/) is freely available both at the linked website and as an app for Android and iOS, and provides related patristic commentaries for each verse.

Answer (score 4):

Newbie can't comment, but Laridian has the Ancient Christian Commentary for $150  https://www.laridian.com/catalog/products/PCDACCS.asp. Buy once, use on multiple platforms. Not connected except by being a happy customer.

Answer (score 1):

Joanna Manley's [The Bible and the Holy Fathers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/096225360X) probably comes closest to what you are looking for, although it only covers those Old Testament readings that fall within the Eastern Orthodox lectionary.

Answer (score 0):

- **[Patristic Bible Commentary](https://sites.google.com/site/aquinasstudybible/)**
- [*The Golden Chain* (*Catena Aurea*)](https://aquinas.cc/la/en/%7ECaMatt) of St. Thomas Aquinas for the Gospels